# LINQ to Entities does not recognize method - async operation

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, async-await

I have a model class with a custom method within:

```
public class Category {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CategoryListViewModel ToListViewModel() {
        return new CategoryListViewModel { 
            Id = this.Id,
            Name = this.Name
        };
    }
```

Nice. In my repository layer, I'm trying to do an async query by using `System.Data.Entity` available methods, such as `ToListAsync()`. However, when I try to call the following piece of code...

```
Context.Categories.Select(c => c.ToListViewModel()).ToListAsync();
```

The compiler complains with the message: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize "ToListViewModel()" method [...]`.

I could do the following to make the query support the method...

```
Context.Categories.AsEnumerable().Select(c => c.ToListViewModel())
```

... although I cannot call `ToListAsync()`, since `IEnumerable` does not implement this method.

How to keep my query async and calling that method above mentioned? Any thoughts?

Thank you all!

Comment: the linq to entities query ends at `Context.Categories.AsEnumerable()`. The calls after that are linq to objects, which is why the projection works

Comment: It should be **extension method** and your ToListViewModel is not.

Comment: Either common method or extension method, it doesn't work. Only if I call "AsEnumerable()" to make it work. But then I'll lose the power of async in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all else fails then do the projection inline

```
Context.Categories.Select(c => new CategoryListViewModel { 
            Id = c.Id,
            Name = c.Name
        }).ToListAsync();
```

So that it can be generated properly as linq to entities has to be able to convert the query to an actual SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks, Nkosi! I'd like to have this method within the model object to make this projection reusable. Let's see if another suggestion will shown up as well.

Comment: The method can stay to be reused on it own. It just cannot be used in the linq to entities because it wont know how to convert your that expression to under laying data source language.